# Preventing Vue from looping

Tags: java, vue.js, vuejs2

I have three fields

hour -- minutes -- and total

If hour or minutes change i want to calculate a total. 
If the total is changed i want to calculate the corresponding minutes and hours.

Example:

1h 30minutes = 1.5 Total

2.25 Total = 2h 15minutes

I am trying to achive this with watch

```
watch: {
            hour: {
                handler: (new_hour, old_hour) => {
                    if(isNaN(new_hour)){
                        manual.hour = old_hour
                    }else{
                        manual.setTotal();
                    }
                }
            },
            minutes: {
                handler: (new_minutes, old_minutes) => {
                    if(isNaN(new_minutes)){
                        manual.minutes = old_minutes
                    }else{
                        if(Number(new_minutes) > 60){
                            manual.minutes = old_minutes
                        }else{
                            manual.setTotal();
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            total:{
                handler: (new_total, old_total) => {
                    if(isNaN(new_total)) {
                        manual.total = old_total;
                    }else{
                        const hour = new_total.split(",")[0];
                        const minutes = new_total.split(",")[1];
                        manual.hour = hour;
                        manual.minutes = (minutes * 60).toFixed(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

However this is resulting in a loop because on handler allways calls the other handler. How can this be done in a smarter way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use onkeyup listener (and/or change)

```js
new Vue({
 el: "#app",
  data: {
   input_h: 0,
   input_m: 0,
   input_t: 0
  },
  methods: {
  update_h (e) {
   this.input_h = Number(e.target.value)
    this.update_t(null)
  },
  update_m (e) {
   this.input_m = Number(e.target.value)
    this.update_t(null)
  },
  update_t (e) {
   if (e === null) {
     this.input_t = Math.round((this.input_h + this.input_m / 60) * 100)/100
    } else {
     this.input_t = Number(e.target.value)
      this.input_h = Math.floor(this.input_t)
      this.input_m = Math.round(this.input_t%1 * 60)
    }
    
  },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input :value="input_h" @keyUp="update_h"/>Hours<br/>
  <input :value="input_m" @keyUp="update_m"/>Minutes<br/>
  <input :value="input_t" @keyUp="update_t"/>Total<br/>
</div>
```

Otherwise, if you want to prevent circular dependency, you need to set up a single source of data, and use computed getters and setters to update the other fields. You don't even have to use a visible field for that.
https://jsbin.com/tagupab/edit has a working example

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked this out, but perhaps you could exchange watchers for computed properties with setter, see ref [Computed setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter)

Note the comment here [circular dependency on observed properties #622 (yyx990803 commented on Dec 11, 2014)](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/622)

> The thing is even when there is a circular dependency, the eventual
> value should be able to stabilize after 1 additional iteration (which
> Vue will then stop because the new evaluated value is the same)

***OR***

I guess you could put

```
if (newValue === oldValue) {
  return
}
```

at the top of each watcher. This is sort of what computed does anyway.